# openrecordset only showing one result

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I use a recordset to read from a table everything works fine and the recordcount function shows me the correct amount, but when I use this simple query or any query I always get 1 as a recordcount.

Here's whats working

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoadQ2()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("test")'test is the name of my table which contains 13 rows

With rs
    Debug.Print .RecordCount
   .Close
End With


Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

and here's whats not working

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoadQ2()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT test.number_id FROM test"


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With rs
    Debug.Print .RecordCount
   .Close
End With


Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I should get the same result with both recordcount right?? Also I'd like to see the line I have in the recordset in the debug is it possible to print the content of the recordset in the debug window??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the contents of the recordset, you can do one of these two options..

```
debug.print rs.fields(0) & ", " & rs.fields(1)
```

or

```
debug.print rs("ColumnNameHere") & ", " & rs("AnotherColumnName")
```

Answer (score 0):

.... found the answer

before doing the Debug.Print .RecourdCount i added .MoveLast and got the right number of recordcount

Looks like recordcount just means at what record that he is not how many records

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement as you already found the answer yourself :)

The Dynaset data type (default for DAO recordset) doesn't fully populate until you go through all its records - since the need to do a .MoveLast before checking how many records it actually has.

I presume that DAO just returns 1 for the recordcount as an easy way to check beforehand if the recordset is empty or not (e.g. recordcount > 0) without having to go through the hassle of moving between records.